# ExoPlayer access values from custom DataSource

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a custom `HttpDataSource` called `MyDataSource`.
To use it with SimpleExoPlayer I do:

```
MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
        () -> {
            return (HttpDataSource)new MyDataSource(/* some parameters */);
        }
).createMediaSource(uri);
```

Then later when I have `MediaSource mediaSource`, I want to access inner values from `MyDataSource`.
How can I do that?
I cannot cast `(MyDataSource) mediaSource`.
I can however cast it into `(ProgressiveMediaSource)mediaSource` - however it's useless, because I cannot get any values from `MyDataSource`, or access the inner `MyDataSource` in any way.

Thank you.